# Running cron produces different result than running its command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, amazon-s3, cron

I have the following script that saves a db backup to s3:

```
# next, backup the mysql `premiered` database to the backups folder
echo successfully backed up mysql databasee
mysqldump --single-transaction -u root test | gzip  > $BACKUPFOLDER/$CONNECT

# finally, save the backups to s3 via s3fs
s3fs test-backups ./s3fs
cp $BACKUPFOLDER/$CONNECT ./s3fs/$CONNECT
echo succeessfully saved sql file to s3
```

When I run this as a shell command, `$ ./backup.sh`, it correctly saves the file to S3. However, when I run this command via cron, it literally saves the file to the local `./s3fs` folder and does not save it to S3. Why does this occur and what do I need to do to fix this?

Comment: That's where you completed the environment.

Answer (score 2):

The cron job executes under user `cron` that does not, by default, have access to your S3 credentials.   I suppose you store them in your `S3_*` environment variables, but the cron job executes with an almost empty environment.